# Why extra query running in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Following is my controller code which is cause running useless query first then

```
        $users = Interest::with('users')->
        whereIn('id',Auth::user()->interests->pluck('id'))
        ->take(5)->get();
```

[query log from laravel dev bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HliJ0.png)

I wonder why extra query before real one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can use this way no extra query will be execute

```
        $interest_ids = Interest::addSelect('id')->whereHas('users', function ($query){
            $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());
        })->get()->pluck('id');

        return User::wherehas('interests', function($query) use($interest_ids){
            $query->whereIn('interest_id', $interest_ids);
        })->take(5)->get();
```

According to your eloquent it seems you are try get other user with same interest and i believe this can be done in your way but it will load multiple queries because of [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-) which is not optimal only according to your case so i think i my way you can have only two queries one for loading interest ids and one for get other user

Answer (score 1):

Because you are eager loading the users with the interests, two queries will be executed. One to retrieve the interests, and one to retrieve the users.

When you would't be eager loading the users, like this:

```
Interest::whereIn('id', Auth::user()->interests->pluck('id'))
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

only `select * from "interests" where "id" in (8, 9, 10) limit 5` would be in the logs.

Next to the two queries in the question, I would also expect a (third) query for `Auth::user()->interests->pluck('id')`.

You can read more in the docs about [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and the resulting queries

Comment: but i need users only that having same interest of current user

Comment: In that case `User::whereHas('interests', function ($query) { return $query->whereIn('id', Auth::user()->interests->pluck('id')); })` would be a better option.

Comment: right i have tested following answer it is good